# Winform datagridview not refreshing

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I've created a datagridview from the tools and chosed the datasource from db. By using dataset of a table I am displaying data in the datagridview. But When I add new data to the database my gridview still looks the same its not refreshing with the new data :( kindly assist. Thanks in advance

Comment: Provide the code that you are trying to do all this stuff and where are you having problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you add data to the database, you need to re-read data from the database to the `DataSet` that is bound to the `DataGridView` control to see the changes. Why don't you add data to the `DataSet`, it will update the `DataGridView` and after you finish, you can update the database using `DataSet`. It is meant to be that way.

Answer (score 0):

Refresh your DataGridView.DataSource when new data is inserted into database.

Answer (score 0):

After the record is added call:

```
yourDataGridView.DataSource = someTableData   
yourDataGridView.DataBind();
```

That should reload the data.